How to find whether a group is dynamic or not from the Google Admin Sdk Api?
I have tried checking the group response(https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/groups) from the Google Admin Sdk Directory Api but couldn’t find any property which could tell whether the group is dynamic or not?
Can somebody please share how can we know whether a group is dynamic or not through Google Api and what Google Apis should be used for getting this info if not Google Admin Sdk Api?

While this is not possible with the Admin SDK, you can use the Cloud Identity API instead. Using the method groups.list with the parameters:

parent : customers/{your customer’s Workspace ID}
view : FULL

will return the list of groups with the format:
{
  "name": "",
  "groupKey": {
    "id": ""
  },
  "displayName": "",
  "description": "",
  "labels": {
    "cloudidentity.googleapis.com/groups.discussion_forum": "",
    "cloudidentity.googleapis.com/groups.dynamic": ""
  }
}

If the group is dynamic, the “labels” field will include the "cloudidentity.googleapis.com/groups.dynamic" tag. Otherwise, this will be absent.
To find your customer ID, you can use this article.
